# Konvajs layer positions not being set as expected

Tags: konvajs

I have an app where I am panning and zooming multiple layers.

However, when I set the position of the layers they are being updated to the wrong values.

For instance, after calling:

```
layer.position({
    x: 12,
    y: 233,
});
```

I would expect

```
layer.getClientRect();
```

to return

```
{
  x: 12,
  y: 233,
}
```

Instead it returns

```
{
  x: -22,
  y: 220,
}
```

Is there any known reason this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realised I wasn't taking into account all the offsets. The x position of a circle is set from the centre while `getClientRect()` returns the width and height including negatives. So `getClientRect()` on a circle with a radius of 50 and x of 0 will actually return {x: -25, y: -25, width: 50, height: 50}.

Comment: Another point to consider is how layer size and position operates. AFAIK (there is space to confirm this) that layer position is the smallest bounding box that surrounds all shapes on the layer - move a shape outside the box and the layer position is altered. Can be unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work for me as advertised in this cut down test. Did you move the stage or something ?

In the snippet below I draw a layer with 4 'corner' rects, display its value from grtClientRect() in 'Layer pos #1' which gives (0, 0), then move the stage to 12, 233 and display its value from grtClientRect() in 'Layer pos #2' which shows (12, 233). I move the layer back up to (12, 23) just for fun thereafter.

```js
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: 1600,
      height: 400
    });

// add a layer
var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

// add 4 corner rects - code I happened to have to hand
var rectCorner = [];
for (i=0;i<4;i=i+1){
  rectCorner[i] = new Konva.Rect({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        fill: 'red',
        opacity: 0.5,
        strokeWidth: 0})
    layer.add(rectCorner[i]);  
}

// put the rects in the corners to give a known layer space
rectCorner[1].position({x:500, y: 0});
rectCorner[2].position({x:500, y: 150});
rectCorner[3].position({x:0, y: 150});
layer.draw();

// get the client rect now
var p = layer.getClientRect();
$('#info1').html('Layer pos #1=' + p.x + ', ' + p.y);

// move the layer...
layer.position({
    x: 12,
    y: 233,
});

// get the client rect now
var p = layer.getClientRect();
$('#info2').html('Layer pos #2=' + p.x + ', ' + p.y);

// move the layer back to the top...
layer.position({
    x: 12,
    y: 23,
});

stage.draw();
```

```css
p
{
  padding: 4px;
  
}
#container
{
  background-color: silver;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<div id='info1'></div>
<div id='info2'></div>

  <div id="container"></div>
            
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.7.6/konva.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Vanquished Wombat. Thanks for that. I kept digging and figured out where I'd gone wrong. I've posted it as the answer.